# why also I can record audio in my Phone app, even if i remove the declaration of android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-permissions

Phone audio recorder is not allowed legally on our Devices sold in Euro, so we need remove the declaration of **android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO** in phone app's Android Manifest.
But even if i did so, my phone app also can record the audio normally.

why?